# Regarding thread safety of servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

Is servlet is thread safe ..? For ex If I open 5 different browsers and sending request to one servlet in the container , is it still thread safe , I means the `service()` method specially

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your question boils down to: *is calling a method from multiple threads on the same object thread safe*. And the answer is: **it depends**. If your object (let it be servlet) is stateless or has only `final` fields, this is completely thread safe. Local variables and parameters are local to the thread (reside on stack, not on heap).

Also each `service()` call receives a distinct instance of `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse`. However, here is an example of an unsafe servlet:

```
public class UnsafeServlet implements Servlet {

    private int counter;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        ++counter;
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Since multiple threads can access the `counter` variable, it has to be secured somehow: either by using `synchronized` (`volatile` is not enough):

```
synchronized(this) {
    ++counter;
}
```

or [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

//...
counter.incrementAndGet();
```

In this particular case `AtomicInteger` is much better since it is lock-free using CAS CPU operations while `synchronized` is a mutex.

Comment: @Tomasz.can you  post here a short example by which you can justify lets say you have a simple servlet and with 2 different browsers you are making a request and by deliberate by one thread you change the value. this thing I want to see..!!Thanks in advance

Comment: Great man , could you please post how would you protect the counter now , and by synchronized will it make impact on performance , could you also please explain a little bit about Atomic Integer

Comment: counter will be shared object, so every member who uses this servlet will have the same `counter` object