# Is there a new bean object created with every request in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not able to understant that only one bean object is created in spring mvc using dispatcher servlet or a new object gets created with every request?

Controller code:-

In the code i am setting the data in the LoginBean Object and setting it in the modelandview object in method abc.

Then in the jsp i am not entering any value for usename, in that case when i submit the form and when the handler method(initform) is called then i am trying to print the same lb.getusername which is not returing me any value.
Not able to understand the concept.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{
ModelAndView mv=null;
EmployeeBean e=new EmployeeBean();
AutoBean autobean;
@Autowired
public LoginController(AutoBean autobean){
    System.out.println("autobean");

    this.autobean=autobean;
}
    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public ModelAndView abc(){

        System.out.println("here");
        System.out.println("here1");
        LoginBean lb=new LoginBean();
        lb.setUsename("ankita");//setting value
        return new ModelAndView("login","loginbean",lb);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/abc1",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView initform(@ModelAttribute("loginbean")LoginBean      lb,BindingResult result,Model model){
        System.out.println("*****"+result.getErrorCount());
        System.out.println("hello");
        autobean.setName("yayme");
        System.out.println(autobean.getName());
        model.addAttribute("autobean", autobean);
        System.out.println("username"+lb.getUsename());// query??
        if(lb.getPassword().equals("ankita"))
        /*{
            mv=new ModelAndView();
            e.setId("1001");
            e.setName("ankita");
            mv.addObject("employee", e);
            mv.addObject("emp", new Emp());

            mv.setViewName("success");
            return mv;
        }*/
        return new ModelAndView("success","emp",new Emp());
        else
            return new ModelAndView("fail","lb1",lb);
    }
```

login.jsp

```
<form:form action="abc1" commandName="loginbean">
username:<form:input path="usename" />
password:<form:password path="password"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Please suggest?

Comment: A `Model` is like request attributes. It is only good for the lifecyle of the request.

Comment: It's slightly different than the underneath data model.

Comment: what about the bean objects then??? is the same bean object shared within all requests or a new bean object is created with every request?

Comment: please someone explain how the bean objects are shared?

Answer (score 14):

Spring's **application context** (*the* bean IoC container, which is responsible for managing bean lifecycle from its instantiation to its destruction) contains bean definitions. These definitions among other attributes contain so called `scope`. This scope can have the following values:

- `singleton` - only one instance of the bean is created during the application lifetime
- `prototype` - every time someone asks (`applicationContext.getBean(...)`) for this bean a new instance is created

You can have some special scopes as well:

- `request` - bean lifecycle is bound to the HTTP request
- `session` - bean lifecycle is bound to the HTTP session

You can even create your own scopes. The **default scope for beans is `singleton`**. So if you don't specify otherwise, the bean is `singleton` (single instance per application).

---

If you are using `component-scan` which searches for classes annotated with `@Component`-like annotations (e.g. `@Controller`), then these classes are automatically registered as bean definitions in application context. The default scope applies to them as well.

If you want to alter scope of these auto-registered beans, you have to use `@Scope` annotation. Check its JavaDoc if you are interested in how to use it.

---

**TL;DR** Your `LoginController` is `singleton`.

Comment: if the object is singleton , thein in my code when i am setting some value then y m i not able to retrieve the same back in the next method from that object itself?

Comment: Hmm... ok, I might have answered a different question. You were actually asking about `@ModelAttribute("loginbean")`, correct?

Comment: i am asking that that "loginbean" model has loginBean object in it with value of usename property set in it ie, LoginBean lb=new LoginBean(); lb.setUsename("ankita");//setting value return new ModelAndView("login","loginbean",lb); Now in the next method when i am trying to retrieve value from this object,then why it is empty ie, System.out.println("username"+lb.getUsename());

Comment: Ok... that is different kind of question. I will try to answer that later today. But basically `@ModelAttribute` beans are re-created with each request, unless the name is specified in `@SessionAttributes` annotation (then it will be created once per session).