# How to manage Hibernate SessionFactory Beans in the following scenario of my spring boot application?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, connection-pooling, sessionfactory

Following is my Bean configuration

```
@Bean
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactoryBean(@Autowired(required = true) HikariDataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFacBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFacBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFacBean.setPackagesToScan("com.project");
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        sessionFacBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        try {
            sessionFacBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFacBean.getObject();

    }
```

I use this 'SessionFactory' Bean in my controller class. As far as I know, spring creates a new thread with new instance of a controller class during multiple requests. In that case, a new instance of 'SessionFactory' bean will also be autowired to the controller ([Explained in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235794/how-does-spring-mvc-handle-multiple-users)). The whole point of this sessionFactory is ConnectionPooling, If the sessionFactory is created for each request then How does the connection pooling works properly.

I have the similar situation for other beans too, HttpClient and MongoTemplate with connection pooling.

Please feel free to edit the question if my understanding is wrong.I'm a newbie to all this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have only one `SessionFactory` for your application. It should be configured during application startup.
2. Each thread should have their own `Session`. There are various approaches how to use a `Session` with requests:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526397/3405171

> In that case, a new instance of 'SessionFactory' bean will also be autowired to the controller

This is incorrect. `@Bean` annotation has `singleton` scope as default. So you will have only one `SessionFactory` for all threads and controllers.

> The whole point of this sessionFactory is ConnectionPooling

To speak more correctly a `DataSource` is responsible for a connection pool. `SessionFactory` is for Hibernate specific stuff like persistent classes metadata, SQL generating etc.

Also keep in mind that Hibernate has  `org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentSessionContext` which controls how the `Session` is bounded to the thread.