# Spring service layer scoped as Singleton - is it thread safe?

Tags: spring, thread-safety, singleton, service-layer

Environment: Spring Container

Say i have the service layer configured as `Singleton` and that there are no instance variables (state variables) in the service class.

```
@Singleton
class MyService{
    public List<String> getNames(){
        List<String> list = entityManager.createQuery("");
        list.add("uknown");

        return list;
    }
}
```

If there are multiple requests (multiple threads) trying to access **simultaneously** the method `getNames()`, is it possible to have any synchronization problems?

For example, is it possible for a request to return the "uknown" name twice?

Comment: //there are no instance variables (state variables) in the service class. What about entityManager?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the method

```
public List<String> getNames(){
    List<String> list = entityManager.createQuery("");
    list.add("uknown");

    return list;
}
```

is scoped to the request. The `entityManager` call returns a new `List` instance to which you add a new `String`. You then return that list. Only the thread that called the method will have access to that `List` instance (unless you later share it).

There are no synchronization problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since service class does not hold any state here (in your example, there are no instance variables in the service class), your service is safe. Local variables and parameters are local to the thread (reside on stack, not on heap).

If you have other objects like say userProfile in your service then since such objects depend on every request, these objects will need to scoped as prototypes. Otherwise, this service is safe.

This is similar to one of my questions. [Are Spring MVC Controllers Singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508405/are-spring-mvc-controllers-singletons)
Do take a look at the link posted in the answer by Tomasz about thread safety in servlets.