# Is the Rest Controller class singleton?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, singleton, spring-restcontroller

I am learning Spring and Spring Boot.
In my Spring boot app, I am using @RestController annotation for one of my classes which receives requests and processes them accordingly.

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {
......
}
```

I want to ask would this class annotated with @RestController be a singleton class?
My thought is that this SampleController would also be a bean and since the default scope is Singleton,
it would be a Singleton class. I want to ask whether I am thinking right.

Comment: Yes , seems you think right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508405/are-spring-mvc-controllers-singletons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Any bean you creating via annotations @Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller, @RestController and @Bean of course by default have Singleton scope. Check
[Bean scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)