# Spring boot: Separate thread pool for specific endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, microservices

Given a microservice in Spring Boot, it offers 2 end-points to be consumed from 2 separate system.
One of this system is critical while the other one is not.
I would like to prevent the "not critical" one to consume (due to unexpected problems) all the threads (or many) of the HTTP thread pool, so I would like to configure separated thread pools for each one of these end-points.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. Using `DeferredResult` is probably the easiest way:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final Executor performancePool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(128);
    private final Executor normalPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

    @GetMapping("/performance")
    DeferredResult<String> performanceEndPoint() {
        DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        performancePool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000); //A long running task
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result.setResult("Executed in performance pool");
        });
        return result;
    }

    @GetMapping("/normal")
    DeferredResult<String> normalEndPoint() {
        DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        normalPool.execute(() -> result.setResult("Executed in normal pool"));
        return result;
    }
}
```

You immediately release the Tomcat thread by returning a `DeferredResult` from a controller, allowing it to serve other requests. The actual response is written to the user when the `.setResult` method is called.

`DeferredResult` is one of the many ways you can perform asynchronous request processing in Spring. Check out this section of the docs to learn more about the other ways:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-async

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure you can prevent, but you can surely increase the thread pool capacity. By default, tomcat (if default server) can handler 200 simultaneous requests , you can increase that number**

Check if this article helps

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893237/can-spring-boot-application-handle-multiple-requests-simultaneously#:~:text=Yes%2C%20Spring%20boot%20can%20handle,can%20handle%20200%20simultaneous%20requests.&text=However%2C%20you%20can%20override%20this,tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893237/can-spring-boot-application-handle-multiple-requests-simultaneously#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20Spring%20boot%20can%20handle,can%20handle%20200%20simultaneous%20requests.&text=However%2C%20you%20can%20override%20this,tomcat).